# Using cat function to write on csv file

Tags: r, cat

I need to add new rows to a CSV using cat function. Would you guys help me, please? I am limited knowledge in R.

here's the file "name1.csv", I am asked to add my name and student ID to the first couple rows.

```r
homework1 <- data.frame (homework1,Total)
homework1 <- data.frame (homework1, Commission)
# Create output file name using name1. All your output will go to this file.
sink("name1.csv")
# send the output to the csv file you just created
write.csv(homework1, file = "name1.csv")
# delete first column of the csv file
# Use cat function to write your name (First Last). This will be Row 1 of csv file. 
cat(file = "name1.csv", "Ibra", "\n", sep = ",", append=TRUE, row.names(F))
```

Comment: `cat(file='name1.csv',"Name\nID")`

Comment: @Waldi Doesn't this overwrite the whole file?

Comment: @MartinGal, you're right, it depends how `add` is understood ;-). `cat(file='name1.csv',"Name\nID",append=T)` should fix it

Comment: Thank you both! it works finally... any idea how to add the name and ID to the top of the csv file instead of the bottom?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know how to use a function, you can call the `help` function on it:

```r
help(cat)
```

> Usage
>
> cat(... , file = "", sep = " ", fill = FALSE, labels = NULL,
> append = FALSE)
>
> Arguments
> ...

And it goes on.

Cat will write to the sink by default. So if you want your name in the file to appear first. Start with catting your name:

```r
sink("name1.csv")
cat("Ibra Lastname\n")  # sink is set, so file is not needed
write.csv(homework1)
```

Note that this will make the csv-file invalid; the first line will be a single string and the rest of the lines will have comma separated values of whatever the shape of homework1 is. This homework makes very little sense to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my comments are being added to the bottom of the csv file. Any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: @ibra your comments? Are you sure they are comments? Comments should be anything starting with `#`. It sounds like you have what you expect to be comments, part of a string. Hard to tell without your code.

Comment: Sorry, here is the code:homework1 <- data.frame (homework1,Total)
homework1 <- data.frame (homework1, Commission)

# Create output file name using name1.  All your output will go to this file.  

sink("name1.csv")

# send the output to the csv file you just created
write.csv(homework1, file = "name1.csv")
#delete first column of the csv file

# Use cat function to write your name (First  Last).  This will be Row 1 of csv file.  

cat(file = "name1.csv", "Ibra", "\n", sep = ",", append=TRUE, row.names(F))

Comment: I meant that my student ID and name are being added to the bottom of the csv file.

Comment: Maybe put that in the question :) One long line of code in a comment isn't really helping... A good question clearly states the input, the expected outcome and shows what you tried to accomplish that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask